# Can I get schemacrawler to ignore the schema name?

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm attempting to make a comparison of two Oracle DBs - I'm running a report on two different schema names - in my case, a schema prefix.  E.g. Using:

```
-schemas=FOO.*
```

then

```
-schemas=BAR.*
```

Is there a way of hiding this prefix from the report, so that it isn't shown as an obvious difference when comparing the two reports?

I know I can use the 'unimportant' text feature in Beyond Compare, but it would be nice to cover this upfront.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious, or maybe no one ever requires this as the schema name is fairly fundamental.  I suppose I am just comparing across schemas.

If it is in the help, I have probably misunderstood what I have read.

Any hints would be welcome.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this was answered in an obvious place...

[SchemaCrawler HowTo](https://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/how-to.html#hide-schema-names)

> **How to hide catalog and schema names in text output**
>
> Change the configuration for the SchemaCrawler
> schemacrawler.format.show_unqualified_names=true  in the
> schemacrawler.config.properties file. This setting will show
> unqualified names of database objects such as tables and prcodures.
> That is, the catalog and schema names will not be displayed. Use with
> care, especially if you have foreign keys that reference tables in
> other schemas, or synonyms.

However, in my situation, the output was actually within returned SQL and procedures etc, so is fundamental to what the DB is holding.
As far as I can see, my best way is to use Beyond Compare or something similar to strip these small  strings out to aid in the comparison.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the SchemaCrawler Oracle plugin? If yes, then the [extra SQL](https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-oracle/src/main/resources/schemacrawler-oracle.show_unqualified_names.sql) should have got executed which would prevent schema names from showing up in the metadata

Comment: @SualehFatehi I'm actually not sure if I am.  I'm currently using the command `schemacrawler.cmd -server=oracle` or is the plugin separate? Do I need to use this from source?  Would the detail level mean I am picking actual sql - or just metadata as I'm seeing things like FROM FOO.. JOIN FOO..
(Note: My DB knowledge isn't great so I could be doing silly things!)

Comment: Turn on logging with `-loglevel=ALL`, and check if the plugin is getting loaded.